# "Projecting" one convex set onto another (though actually, it's just a translation).

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, inner-products, convex-geometry

In linear algebra, we learn that we can project a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ onto a linear subspace $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. I have hunch that this can be generalized considerably. In particular, I think we should be able to replace $x$ and $A$ with arbitrary non-empty convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, call them $X$ and $A$.

In particular, define:

1. The *vector* from $X$ to $A$ is the unique $v$ in the closure of the difference set $A-X$ of minimum length. Such a $v$ always exists from Theorem 1.15 [here](http://www.math.udel.edu/~angell/ch1.pdf). The length of this vector probably equals $\mathrm{inf}_{a \in A,x \in X}d(a,x),$ I guess.
2. The "projection" of $X$ onto $A$ is $X+v$; for sufficiently nice $A$ and $X$, this can be thought of as the minimum translation of $X$ so that it meets $A$.

More generally, this kind of thing should work in any sufficiently nice inner product space.

> **Question.** It would be nice to have standard notation the aforementioned vector $v,$ and for the "projection" of $X$ onto $A$ as defined above. I'd also like some better terminology than "projection" because we're not actually flattening or changing the shape of anything; rather, we're just choosing a vector and translating by that vector.
>
> Is anything approximately standard available?

*Remark.* This notion of projection is [different to Wikipedia's notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projections_onto_convex_sets), which is about finding elements in the intersection of two convex sets.